# parseFloat is giving NaN

Tags: javascript, html, parsefloat

HTML code:

```
    <input type="text" id="iop">
    <button onclick=suh()>Calculate</button>
    <p id="final"></p>
```

Javascript code:

```
let iop=document.getElementById('iop').value;
let num=parseFloat(iop);
function suh(){
    document.getElementById('final').innerHTML=`The square of the number entered is ${num}`;
}
```

The output is:
The square of the number entered is NaN

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("iop").target.value` to retrieve the value?

Comment: Move the code for getting and parsing the value into the function.